# Nvidia 390 driver overheat on optimus laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating, temperature

I am using a Lenovo Legion Y720 laptop, with a GTX 1060 GPU and an i7 7700HQ CPU. I used to have the Nvidia 384 driver installed and everything was fine, until the 390 driver hit and I began to get very high temperatures on my laptop. I tried to manually install the 384 driver, but it just installs the 390 driver instead.

Here is my temps while playing CS GO:

[image]

- I am using Ubuntu 18.04
- The temps on Windows 10 would be max 75-80
- I am using Psensor to measure the temperatures

I could not find this problem anywhere else. Is there a way to force downgrade? If I download the 384 driver from Nvidia, and try to run the file, it just fails to install everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a semi solution to this at:

http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html

I found this script which allows to throttle the cpu down from 3.8 GHZ to 2.5 GHZ which makes the temperature go from 90+ to 77-80 degrees celcius.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: temp_throttle.sh max_temp
# USE CELSIUS TEMPERATURES.
# version 2.20

cat << EOF
Author: Sepero 2016 (sepero 111 @ gmx . com)
URL: http://github.com/Sepero/temp-throttle/

EOF

# Additional Links
# http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html

# Additional Credits
# Wolfgang Ocker <weo AT weo1 DOT de> - Patch for unspecified cpu frequencies.

# License: GNU GPL 2.0

# Generic  function for printing an error and exiting.
err_exit () {
    echo ""
    echo "Error: $@" 1>&2
    exit 128
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    # If temperature wasn't given, then print a message and exit.
    echo "Please supply a maximum desired temperature in Celsius." 1>&2
    echo "For example:  ${0} 60" 1>&2
    exit 2
else
    #Set the first argument as the maximum desired temperature.
    MAX_TEMP=$1
fi


### START Initialize Global variables.

# The frequency will increase when low temperature is reached.
LOW_TEMP=$((MAX_TEMP - 5))

CORES=$(nproc) # Get number of CPU cores.
echo -e "Number of CPU cores detected: $CORES\n"
CORES=$((CORES - 1)) # Subtract 1 from $CORES for easier counting later.

# Temperatures internally are calculated to the thousandth.
MAX_TEMP=${MAX_TEMP}000
LOW_TEMP=${LOW_TEMP}000

FREQ_FILE="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies"
FREQ_MIN="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq"
FREQ_MAX="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq"

# Store available cpu frequencies in a space separated string FREQ_LIST.
if [ -f $FREQ_FILE ]; then
    # If $FREQ_FILE exists, get frequencies from it.
    FREQ_LIST=$(cat $FREQ_FILE) || err_exit "Could not read available cpu frequencies from file $FREQ_FILE"
elif [ -f $FREQ_MIN -a -f $FREQ_MAX ]; then
    # Else if $FREQ_MIN and $FREQ_MAX exist, generate a list of frequencies between them.
    FREQ_LIST=$(seq $(cat $FREQ_MAX) -100000 $(cat $FREQ_MIN)) || err_exit "Could not compute available cpu frequencies"
else
    err_exit "Could not determine available cpu frequencies"
fi

FREQ_LIST_LEN=$(echo $FREQ_LIST | wc -w)

# CURRENT_FREQ will save the index of the currently used frequency in FREQ_LIST.
CURRENT_FREQ=2

# This is a list of possible locations to read the current system temperature.
TEMPERATURE_FILES="
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/temp1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/device/temp1_input
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/temp1_input
null
"

# Store the first temperature location that exists in the variable TEMP_FILE.
# The location stored in $TEMP_FILE will be used for temperature readings.
for file in $TEMPERATURE_FILES; do
    TEMP_FILE=$file
    [ -f $TEMP_FILE ] && break
done

[ $TEMP_FILE == "null" ] && err_exit "The location for temperature reading was not found."


### END Initialize Global variables.


### START define script functions.

# Set the maximum frequency for all cpu cores.
set_freq () {
    # From the string FREQ_LIST, we choose the item at index CURRENT_FREQ.
    FREQ_TO_SET=$(echo $FREQ_LIST | cut -d " " -f $CURRENT_FREQ)
    echo $FREQ_TO_SET
    for i in $(seq 0 $CORES); do
        # Try to set core frequency by writing to /sys/devices.
        { echo $FREQ_TO_SET 2> /dev/null > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq; } ||
        # Else, try to set core frequency using command cpufreq-set.
        { cpufreq-set -c $i --max $FREQ_TO_SET > /dev/null; } ||
        # Else, return error message.
        { err_exit "Failed to set frequency CPU core$i. Run script as Root user. Some systems may require to install the package cpufrequtils."; }
    done
}

# Will reduce the frequency of cpus if possible.
throttle () {
    if [ $CURRENT_FREQ -lt $FREQ_LIST_LEN ]; then
        CURRENT_FREQ=$((CURRENT_FREQ + 1))
        echo -n "throttle "
        set_freq $CURRENT_FREQ
    fi
}

# Will increase the frequency of cpus if possible.
unthrottle () {
    if [ $CURRENT_FREQ -ne 1 ]; then
        CURRENT_FREQ=$((CURRENT_FREQ - 1))
        echo -n "unthrottle "
        set_freq $CURRENT_FREQ
    fi
}

get_temp () {
    # Get the system temperature.

    TEMP=$(cat $TEMP_FILE)
}

### END define script functions.

echo "Initialize to max CPU frequency"
unthrottle


# Main loop
while true; do
    get_temp # Gets the current temperature and set it to the variable TEMP.
    if   [ $TEMP -gt $MAX_TEMP ]; then # Throttle if too hot.
        throttle
    elif [ $TEMP -le $LOW_TEMP ]; then # Unthrottle if cool.
        unthrottle
    fi
    sleep 3 # The amount of time between checking temperatures.
done
```

How to use:

sudo ./temp_throttle.sh 75

(75 is the temperature, i.e. throttle at 75+ degrees celcius)

The terminal will begin printing that the CPU is throttling and it begins to go down from 3.8 GHz (in my case) to 3.7 and so forth. Unfortunately it continues to do that until it reaches 800 MHz which makes everything lag. What I found out was that when it reaches the throttle to for example, 2.8 GHz, just hit ctrl+C to end the process and it will stay there. If you want to return to maximum power again, just set some high temperature like 80 or above and it will return to 3.8 GHz or higher depending on your CPU.